# Rails Background Process

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble finding the gem/solution I need to solve this problem. So basically when a request comes in, I want to fork a thread (or background process) and start running that immediately (with no delay). However, s I tried using dalayed_jobs but it seemed to want to a queue, and won't just start the command right away. Is there any way to do this in rails?

**Update**

```
#user_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_user  #process to be forked
  render json:@user
end

#user.rb

def update_user
  # code to update user
end
handle_asynchronously :update_user
```

Thanks,
DO

Comment: if you don't mention the time in delayed job it will run immediately.

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais they are put into the database but never actually ran.

Comment: will you please check last entry of delayed_job following attributes, failed_at, last_error and run_at

Comment: You need be running a Delayed Job worker process to monitor the database.

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais failed_at= NULL, last_error=NULL, and run_at={THE TIME IT WAS PUT IN}. However, I know it's not run

Comment: try manually running the delayed jobs, if you have configured it properly then it must be working, bundle exec rake jobs:work (it will run all the delayedjobs)

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais Yes this works,but how will it do it automatically.

Comment: will you please show the code how you are making call to delay job

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais i'm just called the method, user.update_user, which at the bottom it says handle_asynchronously :update_user

Comment: please show some of your code in question it would be much helpful for  me to answer

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais update is there

Comment: You need to run the delayed_job daemon (so it runs in the background). `script/delayed_job start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delayed Job runs the process immediately after it is triggered (according to your code) since you did not specify when to run it. To get it to work, you can run `rake jobs:work` but you probably want the process to be run in the background so start the delayed_job daemon in the terminal.

```
script/delayed_job start
```

Answer (score 0):

From Ruby 1.9 you should be able to do that by calling Process.spawn "your command", example:

```
pid = Process.spawn("./some_shell_script.sh")
puts "A shell script has just been launched with a Process ID of #{pid}"
```

This command should spawn a seperate process and return the process id.

Comment: I would like to do it in a rails model if possible. Or else I would have to do a lot of logic with SQL and remaking my models